# Approximate a Wiener Process by a Karhunen-Loève expansion

Tags: random, random-process

I'm trying to approximate a Wiener Process by a [Karhunen-Loeve expansion](https://www5.in.tum.de/lehre/vorlesungen/algo_uq/ss17/10_random_fields.pdf) (see slide 20) with the following code:

```
lists = {};
listskl = {};

Wn[t_, n_, ξ_] := 1/Sqrt[n] Sum[ξ[[k]], {k, 1, n t}];
KL[t_, n_, ξ_] := Sqrt[2.] Sum[(Sin[(k + 0.5) Pi t]/((k + 0.5) Pi)) ξ[[k]], {k, 1, n}];

For[i = 1, i < 10, i++,
  ξ = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0., 1], 1000];
  wiener = Table[{t, Wn[t, 100, ξ]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.01}];
  kl = Table[{t, KL[t, 100, ξ]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.01}];
  AppendTo[lists, wiener];
  AppendTo[listskl, kl];
]

ListLinePlot[lists]
ListLinePlot[listskl]
```

[image: top: Wiener process plot; bottom: KL approximation]

The results are quite different but, as far as I understand, they should match for the same random samples. What am I missing here?

Comment: I wonder if your problem might be in your interpretation of the formulae. At a glance, I I probably wouldn't use `AppendTo` and a `For` loop, but apart from style, your Mathematica implementation looks fine.

Comment: The realizations are not meant to match.  The idea is that each method yields a realization of a Wiener process, so that statistically, you expect the same behaviors.  Also, you are only using 100 of the random normals in each case.  Why not try using a 1000 (or more) in each summation.  The results should improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a small change to your definition:

```
pKL[t_, n_, \[Xi]_] := 
  Sqrt[2] Sum[(Sin[(k + 1/2) Pi t]/((k + 1/2) Pi)) \[Xi][[k + 1]], {k, 0, n - 1}];
```

Checks:

```
n = 10^2;
nsim = 10^4;
csi = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, nsim}];
out = pKL[0.86, n, csi];
Through[{Mean, Variance}[out]] (* expected: {0, 0.86} *)
(* {-0.0010983, 0.867538} *)

out = pKL[0.123, n, csi];
Through[{Mean, Variance}[out]] (* expected: {0, 0.123} *)
{-0.0035637, 0.125121}
```

Comment: I don't understand your change: you now run the $k$ index from 0 to $n-1$ but then use $k+1$ in `Part`: isn't that functionally the same as the OP? Does your KL better approximate a true Wiener process obtained from the same random variables $\xi$, as shown on slide 21 of the OP's linked PDF?

Comment: I'm just including the `k=0` term in the sum as it is (I think) ` Sum[(Sqrt[2] Sin[(k + 1/2) Pi t]/((k + 1/2) Pi))^2, {k, 0, Infinity}]` which equals `t` and therefore it matches the variance of `WienerProcess[]`.

Comment: The `Sqrt[2.] Sum[(Sin[(k + 0.5) Pi t]/((k + 0.5) Pi)) ξ[[k]], {k, 1, Infinity}];` corresponds to a stochastic process, and not to `t`.

Comment: @Diogo Yes I understand that, however if you compute the variance of your expression (without the k=0 term in the sum) then I think it will not match `t`, which is the variance of the process you are trying to approximate (in your words "The results are quite different").

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what You mean that it's not possible to match the graphics (KL and Wiener) exactly, but the variance at a given time should be equal to time `t`  for both processes?

Comment: @Diogo Yes I think so. The variance of the approximate process should be close to `t` and its mean close to `0`; you tune `n` until the approximation is good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I made small changes to the @b.gates.you.know.what code in order to try to clearly illustrate what is happening here.

First we create the stochastic processes (Wiener and its approximation by the Karhunen Loève Expansion) and compute its mean and variance in a specific time `t`.

```
n = 100;
nsamples = 1000;
Wn[t_, n_, \[Xi]_] := 1/Sqrt[(n - 1)] Sum[\[Xi][[k + 1]], {k, 0, (n - 1) t}];
pKL[t_, n_, \[Xi]_] := Sqrt[2] Sum[(Sin[(k + 1/2) Pi t]/((k + 1/2) Pi)) \[Xi][[k + 1]], {k,0, n - 1}];
csi = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, nsamples}];
out = pKL[0.5, n, csi];
out2 = Wn[0.5, n, csi];
Through[{Mean, Variance}[out]] (*expected:{0,0.5}*)
Through[{Mean, Variance}[out2]](*expected:{0,0.5}*)
```

Then, several stochastic processes are computed for `t` varying from zero to one:

```
steps = 50;
outklvec = Table[0, {steps + 1}, {nsamples}];
outwienervec = Table[0, {steps + 1}, {nsamples}];
delta = 1./steps;
istep = 1;
For[t = 0, t <= 1, t += delta,
  outkl = pKL[t, n, csi];
  outwi = Wn[t, n, csi];
  outklvec[[istep]] = Table[{t, outkl[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[outkl]}];
  outwienervec[[istep]] = 
   Table[{t, outwi[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[outwi]}];
  istep++;
  ];
```

A specific time is chosen and plotted in red for several realizations of the process, and the its mean and variance are computed once more:

```
step = 26;
valatt = outklvec[[step]];
Print["time = ", valatt[[1, 1]]];
pointplot = 
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Table[Point[valatt[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[valatt]}]}];
Show[ListLinePlot[Transpose[outklvec]], pointplot]
Mean[Transpose[valatt][[2]]] 
Variance[Transpose[valatt][[2]]]

valatt2 = outwienervec[[step]];
pointplot = 
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Table[Point[valatt2[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[valatt2]}]}];
Show[ListLinePlot[Transpose[outwienervec]], pointplot]
Mean[Transpose[valatt2][[2]]] 
Variance[Transpose[valatt2][[2]]]
```

[image]